# j_security_check favicon Issue in Chrome Browser

Tags: favicon

My Web Application deployed in Glassfish server is using j_security_check for form authentication. I have observed after logging in successfully, Chrome browser is redirecting the page to /favicon.ico instead of originally requested page. This behaviour is observed only in Chrome browser and it is sporadic in nature.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This issue is resolved now. I have included favicon.ico in security-constraint in web.xml file.